# Strange warning in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide

I work under Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

Recently I moved the solution to another directory.
It works as before, but now, I have a warning in in the top position of every source code tap: it is in German, but translated it says:

```
 The directory specified in the option -current directory is no 
 directory: <and then the the name of the old place where it was before>
```

But how can I change the current directory? I found no place where to do that...

[image: Snapshot of IDE]

Comment: Could this be an introduce typographic error that occurred as part of the "move"?